# what does it mean to say 'regionally advertised'

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english

An article says ' the types of food supplier are regionally advertised and nationally advertised '.

I thought the word 'advertised' is related to 'advertisement', so the words
**regionally advertised** and **nationally advertised** are a bit hard to interpret. In this specific context, do they mean the food is offer by region or country in this context?

Comment: Looking up "regional" in a dictionary should answer this immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regionally advertised** means that the product is advertised in or to a specific region – most likely on local TV channels, radio stations, and newspapers/magazines.

**Nationally advertised** is similar, except the scope of the advertising is nationwide. The product is likely advertised on TV channels broadcast to the entire nation, or in newspapers/magazines distributed across the entire nation. This may include using multiple regional TV channels/etc.

Similarly, **internationally advertised** would mean that the product was advertised in multiple countries (probably on nationwide broadcasters of those countries).